# Keeping Chrome from freezing when playing HTML5 video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a website with HTML5 video. When viewing the page with Google Chrome, Chrome freezes the tab with an "Aw, Snap!" error intermittently. The page stops rendering and then times out about 15 seconds later. This happens about once every five times the page is loaded. It happens much more often when there are multiple videos on the page (about once out of every two times), so it seems like the problem is perhaps occurring on a per-video basis. How can I start debugging this problem? Chrome doesn't give any obvious JavaScript errors. I am using the Video For Everybody video playing code.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it just your site, or do other sites have a similar issue?

Comment: It happens on some other sites, but not all. http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html has the problem. http://videojs.com/ does not seem to.

Comment: What version of Google Chrome are you using? Which OS?

Comment: 9.0.597.107 (0) on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be related.  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72985

Although the bug is for a page with many videos, I've found the same behavior with Chrome 9 on a page with one video.  Chrome 10 beta does not exhibit the behavior and removing the preload attribute seems to fix the issue as well.

Comment: Removing preload didn't seem to work for me, but upgrading to Chrome 10 did.